# Node JS Asynchronous concept

Tags: node.js, multithreading, async-await

I am having a hard time understanding how the pool in NodeJS works. How does async function work all at a time?

Does the event loop allocate threads from the thread pool for every async Function? If yes, please look at the code below

```
const saySomething = async(arg)=>{
    try{
        for(i=0;i<=10000;i++){
            console.log(arg)
        }
    }
    catch{
    }
}



saySomething("Muthu")
    .then(()=>{})
    .catch(()=>{})
saySomething("Raj")
    .then(()=>{})
    .catch(()=>{})
saySomething("Candy")
    .then(()=>{})
    .catch(()=>{})
saySomething("Python")
    .then(()=>{})
    .catch(()=>{})
```

While running, I am seeing like it is being executed only by one thread; even though 4 threads are running concurrently by time-sharing and context-switching in OS. If not, is my assumption wrong? Please, help me out...

Comment: "I am seeing like it is being executed only by one thread;" — Yes.

Comment: "even though 4 threads are running concurrently by time-sharing and context-switching in OS" — No, there is only one thread.